# How do I create a borderless frame?

Tags: frames

That is, how can I (from Lisp) create a frame similar to the one that `x_create_tip_frame` (called by `x-show-tip` in the C sources) creates when `x-gtk-use-system-tooltips` is `nil`?

My original guess was that the relevant part of the C code was this call:

```
x_default_parameter (f, parms, Qborder_width, make_number (0),
             "borderWidth", "BorderWidth", RES_TYPE_NUMBER);
```

Unfortunately, neither `(set-frame-param (selected-frame) 'border-width 0)` nor `(make-frame '((border-width . 0)))` (both inspired from the call above) yield a borderless frame. Still, `x-show-tip` works fine, so there must be a reliable way :)

Bottom line: **How do I create a frame without a border added by the window manager?**

Comment: Isn't this something that's handled by the window manager rather than Emacs?

Comment: @Dan: No; Emacs can request a borderless frame. It already does for tooltip, for example.

Comment: Cross-posted to emacs-devel: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2016-02/msg00713.html

Answer (score 4):

Emacs 26 now has an `undecorated` frame parameter for this purpose:

```
(make-frame '((undecorated . t)))
```

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25408#77